# cancel computingThread from GUI

Tags: java, javafx

i know, similar questions have been asked a lot in the past, but they don't fit my problem and i have no idea how to tackle it.

my javafx application creates a computingThread which will run a given algorithm (in this case an implemented interface with a work() method), so i have no idea what is actually happening inside the work method.

the usual approach with checking in every run of a loop if the thread got interrupted doesn't work here.

```
    public void executeAlgorithm(Space2DAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
    mainComputingTask = new Task<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void call()
            throws Exception
        {
            try
            {
                algorithm.work(new Vector<GeometricShape>(currentItems.keySet()));
            }
            catch ( RuntimeException e )
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    }
    t = new Thread(mainComputingTask);
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("UNCAUGHt");
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
```

i shortened the code of the method in order to display only the relevant part. i hope my problem gets clear now.
i already tried different methods for running the `mainComputingTask` and the one in the snippet above is the best working for me.

is it somehow possible to stop `Thread t` or `Task maincomputingTask` programatically?

thanks a lot in advance

edit: i'm using a `Task` wrapped in a `Thread` here in order to handle events like `onSucceeded` and so on

Comment: Looks like you'd have to hand a flag on down to your algorithm implementation?

Comment: but that would assume i can edit the code of the implementation which i want to avoid. the gui should know nothing about the algorithm itself.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with adding some sort of interface with a `terminate` to your (range?) of algorithms - it doesn't bind it to your GUI and it's a valid use case here. There is no way to force a `Thread` to stop.

Comment: "There is no way to force a Thread to stop" ok, thanks a lot... than i will investigate again about the use of this function as i want to take away as much as possible from the implementor of an algorithm

Comment: You don't really need to create a flag specifically either; if you can arrange to pass a reference to the task (as a `FutureTask`, if needed) to your algorithm, then your algorithm can just check `task.isCancelled()` at appropriate times.

Comment: Killing the thread doesn't always get you what you want. What happens if the algorithm implementor has decided to start new threads as part of the algorithm? Killing the main thread won't necessarily kill the others. Much better to tell the algorithm implementors that they need to implement a 'cancel' check.

Comment: ok, thank you all a lot. i wasn't really convinced about this option, but your general advices in other questions lead me to the assumption that you know about good practices ;)  i will rethink this option and add a simple way for terminating a thread/task early.

but one last question: why does the `Task` allows you to implement a `onCancelled` listener if i can't really cancel it?

Comment: `Task` provides a mechanism for cancelation; calling `cancel()` will move the task into a `cancelled` state. However, since the `call()` method is implemented by external code, it is the responsibility of that code to properly observe cancelation. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) (last paragraph before "Examples").